# HTML Canvas reset drawing point after transform and rotate

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have this simple `canvas` webpage that lets user upload photo from camera by using `HTML input type file`. The idea is to let user make free drawing on their image. However, I have one problem.

On some devices, the image from camera is drawn onto the canvas with wrong orientation, so I have to provide users a button to rotate their image to get the drawing with correct orientation.

The problem is that after the canvas has been transformed and rotated to get the correct orientation, the drawing coordinates seems to be way off. For example, if I draw straight horizontal line, I get instead straight vertical line after the image has been rotated once. I think the problem lies in that fact that canvas orientation is changed.

So how can I correct back the drawing coordinate after image has been transformed and rotate? My code is below..

```js
window.onload = init;
var canvas, ctx, file, fileURL;
var mousePressed = false;
var lastX, lastY;

function init(){
 canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas')
 ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
 canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', touchstartHandler, false)
 canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', touchmoveHandler, false)
 canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', touchendHandler, false)
 canvas.addEventListener('mouseleave', touchcancelHandler, false)
}

function touchstartHandler(e){
 e.preventDefault()
 mousePressed = true;
 Draw(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop, false);
}
function touchmoveHandler(e){
 e.preventDefault()
 if (mousePressed) {
     Draw(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop, true);
 }
}

function touchendHandler(e){
 e.preventDefault()
 if (mousePressed) {
     mousePressed = false;
 }
}

function touchcancelHandler(e){
 e.preventDefault()
 if (mousePressed) {
     mousePressed = false;
 }
}

function Draw(x, y, isDown) {
    if (isDown) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
        ctx.lineWidth = 12;
        ctx.lineJoin = "round";
        ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    lastX = x;
    lastY = y;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Portrait</title>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas><br/>
 <input type="file"  onchange="fileUpload(this.files)" id="file-input" capture="camera"><br/><br/>
 <button onclick="rotate()">Rotate</button>

 <script>
  var file, canvas, ctx, image, fileURL;
  function fileUpload(files){
   file = files[0]
   fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file)
   canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas')
   canvas.style.backgroundColor = "blue"
   ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
   image = new Image()
   
        image.onload = function() {
          canvas.width = 500
          canvas.height = (500*this.height)/this.width
          ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
          ctx.save();
        }
     image.src = fileURL
   }

   function rotate(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
    ctx.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2)
    ctx.rotate(90*Math.PI/180)
    ctx.translate(-canvas.width/2, -canvas.height/2)
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
   }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to [**save**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save) the canvas state before rotating and translating, and then [**restore**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/restore) the state when the transformation is  done.

```js
var file, canvas, ctx, image, fileURL, rotation = 90;

function fileUpload(files) {
   file = files[0]
   fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file)
   canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas')
   canvas.style.backgroundColor = "blue"
   ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
   image = new Image()

   image.onload = function() {
      canvas.width = 500
      canvas.height = (500 * this.height) / this.width
      ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
   }
   image.src = fileURL
}

function rotate() {
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   ctx.save(); //save canvas state
   ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
   ctx.rotate(rotation * Math.PI / 180);
   ctx.translate(-canvas.width / 2, -canvas.height / 2);
   ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   rotation += 90;
   ctx.restore(); //restore canvas state
}
```

```css
canvas {border: 1px solid red}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<br/>
<input type="file" onchange="fileUpload(this.files)" id="file-input" capture="camera">
<br/>
<br/>
<button onclick="rotate()">Rotate</button>
```

Comment: I have tried this option before and it worked, but the problem is that I can rotate only once and the rotation seems to stop working after one time. Do you why it is stopping rotating after one time?

Comment: I have one more question. For example, after the image has been rotated once, there are some blank spaces on the left and right sides of the canvas where there is no drawing of image. Now I want to resize the canvas so that  the canvas size is the same as the image, but I do not know how to get the width and height of the image after it has been rotated and transformed. It seems the the width and height of the image are changed.

Comment: check edited answer and I don't see any blank space. *(it's a diff. question btw, can't be answered here)*

Comment: With "blank space", I meant the blue background color of the canvas I get after one rotation.

Comment: I just want to resize the size of the canvas exactly as the size of the rotated image. Now after rotating image from landscape to portrait, I suddenly get a canvas with "blank spaces" that corresponds to "blue background" as you can see after rotating the image once. Take a look at here: [link](http://imgur.com/K5IopFO)

Comment: Ya I got you! But this doesn't fall within the bound of your original question. You should rather ask a new question with adequate details.

Comment: Hi, I have created a new question just for that one. Could you please answer it here? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44825002/rezize-html-canvas-size-after-transformed-operation)

Answer (score 0):

### Simple rotation

Quickest way to rotate the image by steps of 90 deg

```
ctx.setTransform(
      0,1, // direction of x axis
      -1,0 // direction of y axis
      canvas.width,0   // location in pixels of the origin (0,0)
);
```

Then draw the image

```
ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
```

Rather than use `ctx.restore()` that can be slow in many situations you can eset only the transform to the default with.

```
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
```

#### Rotate 90, 180, -90deg

Thus to rotate 90 deg

```
ctx.setTransform(0,1,-1,0,canvas.width,0);
ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
```

Thus to rotate 180 deg

```
ctx.setTransform(-1,0,0,-1,canvas.width,canvas.height);
ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
```

Thus to rotate -90 deg

```
ctx.setTransform(0,-1,1,0,0,canvas.height);
ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
```

Comment: Hi, could you answer this one? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44825002/rezize-html-canvas-size-after-transformed-operation)

I have already got this question.